# Dangling callbacks: return response before every callback has returned

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

> **Question:** Would you consider dangling callbacks as bad node.js style or even dangerous? If so under which premise?

**Case:** as described below, imagine you need to make calls to a DB in an express server that updates some data. Yet the client doesn't need to be informed about the result. In this case you could return a response immediately, **not** waiting for the asynchronous call to complete. This would be described as *dangling callback* for lack of a better name.

**Why is this interesting?:** Because tutorials and documentation in most cases show the case of waiting, in worst cases teaching callback hell. Recall your first experiences with say express, mongodb and passport.

---

**Example:**

```
'use strict'
const assert = require('assert')
const express = require('express')

const app = express()

function longOperation (value, cb) {
  // might fail and: return cb(err) ...here

  setTimeout(() => {
    // after some time invokes the callback
    return cb(null, value)
  }, 4000)
}

app.get('/ping', function (req, res) {
  // do some declartions here
  //
  // do some request processesing here

  // call a long op, such as a DB call here.
  // however the client does not need to be
  // informed about the result of the operation
  longOperation(1, (err, val) => {
    assert(!err)
    assert(val === 1)
    console.log('...fired callback here though')
    return
  })

  console.log('sending response here...')
  return res.send('Hello!')
})

let server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Starting test:')
})
```

Comment: Might be a better question for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ instead. That being said, if the client doesn't need or care about the internal call and whether or not it errors, don't make them wait (IMO). Handle your results / errors internally, but let the client move on. Make sure you consider what happens when a client makes a follow up request when the internals of their first request hasn't finished yet.

Comment: Yeah for me that's pretty okay. Actually I like this pattern. Just want to know whether my opinion is wrong in any way. I'd leave it since there might be node specifics like gc and memory leaks. But would you see that in a less node-y way in programmers. then? If you have a +1 I'll do it...

Comment: Personally, I think this pattern is the best way of doing it (with callbacks, anyways), and I've used it without issue in nodejs. If there's no reason to make the client wait for internals, then all you're doing is hurting the user experience by making them wait. I would exercise caution if the user intends to do something like update a record though. In that case, I would make sure to wait to resolve the response until the changes are fully saved, or the client may think an action occurred which wasn't made permanent. I don't really have an answer, though, since this is fairly opinion based.

Comment: Sure. Curious for those experiences though. There might be different. Some CAP theorem guys, or what not. I'll keep this open for a couple of days in that form and then I'll make a change. Thanks for your opnion!

Comment: Of course. I'm sure there may be some people that disagree with me. But I can say from personal experience in multiple languages (C# `Task.ContinueWith()` instead of awaiting the Task comes to mind) that the pattern itself works in at least some scenarios, as long as you know how to handle the errors and such internally and don't require client intervention. Maybe others have had different experiences than me.

Comment: @dvlsg when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat I agree. I meant that it should be (potentially) deleted here and posted there instead, since it's more of a design pattern question than a javascript / nodejs question, but I think it works here since the examples are in those languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, this is basically what called a "fire and forget" service in other contexts, and could also be the first step in a good design implementing command-query response separation.

I don't consider it a "dangling callback", the response in this case acknowledges that the request was received.  Your best bet here would be to make sure your response includes some kind of hypermedia that lets clients get the status of their request later, and if it's an error they can fix have the content at the new resource URL tell them how.

Think of it in the case of a user registration workflow where the user has to be approved by an admin, or has to confirm their email before getting access.